# Amazon S3 redirects to /index.html not root of page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have two sites statically hosted at S3.

Site example-one.com should redirect to example-two.com.

I added a redirect in the S3 bucket for example-one.com. 
Like shown in the picture below.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p6IU.png]

**Problem: entering example-one.com results in example-two.com/index.html**

**Question: How can I make it redirect to **example-two.com** and not example-two.com/index.html ?**

When I access example-two.com directly it results in example-two.com as intended.

example-two.com has the S3 static site setting *index document* given as index.html

I use CloudFront for both domains. They previously had set the setting *default root object* as *index.html*, however I removed this earlier today so it's blank now.

To see it live access [the link](https://freemi.dk)

Please specify if further details are needed :-)